# Display the saved values of in separate dropdown list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist in edit view that has a value from the database. What I want to do is to display the saved value in separate dropdown list. For example, I have saved two different data in database with same foreign key to determine that these two records are treated as one. (See below sample image)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/YyvjA.jpg

I am only using single-selection dropdown list and I am only looping the count of records to determine how many dropdown list to display in the edit page. So if I have "No harm event" and "Complaints" events, this must be displayed in separate dropdown list because what I did now is they are both displaying in one dropdown list so the result is it looks like the record is duplicated (see image below) but actually these two records are in each of the dropdown list.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z43Rs.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnLG7.jpg

VIEW

```
//for loop to count records that will determine how many dropdown list to be displayed
@for (var i = 0; i < Model.SavedEventsToList.Where(a => a.incidentReportId == Model.IRId).Count(); i++)
 {
    <tr>
       <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
          <div class="input-group">  
              <select class="form-control pseEventDDLInEdit" id="pseEventListInEdit" name="pseAddedEvent">
                @{
                   foreach (var item in Model.SavedEventsToList)
                   {
                      if (item.selected == "yes")
                      {
                         if (item.incidentReportId == Model.IRId)   //this is the foreign key that determine these two records are as one
                         {
                            <option value=@item.pseEventsId selected>@item.pseEventsName</option>
                         }
                       }
                       else
                       {
                         <option value=@item.pseEventsId>@item.pseEventsName</option>
                       }                                                        
                    }
                  }
                </select>
            </div>
         </td>
     </tr>
  }
```

CONTROLLER

```
public ActionResult Edit(Guid? id)
{
  IMRBusinessLogic imrLogic = new IMRBusinessLogic();
  var imrRepo = new IMRRepository();
  IMRDTO imr = imrRepo.GetIRDetailsForEdit(id);
  imr.SavedEventsToList = imrLogic.SavedEvents(id);

   return View(imr);
}


public List<PSESavedEventsDTO> SavedEvents(Guid? incidentReportId)
{
  using (IREntities db = new IREntities())
  {
     var events = (from a in db.SavedPatientSafetyEvents(incidentReportId)
                select new PSESavedEventsDTO
                {
                  pseSavedEventId = a.pse_saved_event_category_and_subcategory_id,
                  pseEventsId = a.pse_events_id,
                  pseEventsName = a.pse_events_name,
                  seqNum = a.seq_num,
                  incidentReportId = a.incident_report_id,
                  savedRowIndex = a.saved_row_index,
                  selected = a.selected
                }).ToList();
       return events;
      }
}
```

I need to separate them so the user can still have an option to edit each of these two records.

This is the expected output I need: https://i.stack.imgur.com/X9lcz.jpg

Can someone help me with this.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the solution in this. I just use foreach instead of for loop, and I get the desired output I need.

```
@foreach (var index in Model.SavedEventsToList.Where(a => a.savedRowIndex != 0))
{
<tr>
  <td style="border-bottom:none !important;border-top:none !important;">
     <div class="input-group">
        <select class="form-control pseEventDDLInEdit" id="pseEventListInEdit" name="pseAddedEvent">
        @{
           foreach (var item in Model.SavedEventsToList)
           {
              if (item.selected == "yes")
              {
                 if (item.incidentReportId == Model.IRId && item.savedRowIndex == index.savedRowIndex)
                 {
                    <option value=@item.pseEventsId selected>@item.pseEventsName</option>
                 }
              }
              else
              {
                 <option value=@item.pseEventsId>@item.pseEventsName</option>
              }
           }
         }
        </select>
        <span title="Patient Safety Events Description" class="input-group-addon" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="right" data-trigger="hover" data-html="true" href="#" id="login"><i class="fa fa-info-circle"></i></span>
     </div>
  </td>
</tr>
}
```